# Chrome Extension addEventListener null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I just started learning JS a few weeks ago and am trying to build a Chrome Extension. I've build a `manifest.json`, `popup.html`, `popup.js`, and `content.js` file.

When I try running the background page console on Chrome to see if the `popup.js` is working I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at popup.js:8
```

I've tried moving the script in the html to the bottom of the body, but it still ends in an error and have tried implementing:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //   My code here.. ( Your code here  )
    });
```

in my `popup.js` and the `windows.onload` method, but still haven't been able to get rid of the error.

If someone could please point out any errors in my code and tell me what is wrong I would really appreciate it. Thanks

POPUP HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Like IG Links</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h3><center>Paste Links Below</center></h3>
    <hr>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="urls"></textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="5" id="counter" disabled></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" align="center" style="width:60px;"
            id="start">Start</button>

    <br> 
    <br>

    <button type="submit" align="right" style="width:60px;"
            id="stop">Stop</button>          

   <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>              

</body>

</html>
```

CONTENT JS

```
console.log('CHROME');
```

POPUP JS

```
console.log('background running');

function loadUrls() {
console.log("123");
}

var startbutton = document.getElementById("start");
startbutton.addEventListener('click', loadUrls);
```

MANIFEST JSON

```
{ 
"manifest_version": 2,      
"name": "Like IG Links",
"version": "1.0",    
"description": "Like IG Links",

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }    
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
    },

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",  
"default_popup": "popup.html"                 
},

"permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading about the extensions [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) first. The background page and the popup are different things and you are searching for an element in the background page that is a blank html template with a script attached to it, so it will not find your `startbutton`. When you click your extension icon though everything works as expected and you won't see any erorrs in the popup console that you get by choosing its option after right clicking the extension icon in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the background script portion of the manifest. After updating the extension, the errors should disappear. In an extension I am working on, I had jquery.js and popup.js in the HTML and in the manifest. The background script tag for the manifest is for logic that tracks browser events and responds to them persistently, not for the js behind the extension HTML.